# Definition of Cuntz algebra clarification about orthogonality

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

The Cuntz algebra is sometimes defined as the (universal) C*-algebra on isometries $s_1,\ldots, s_n$ satisfying $\sum s_is_i^* = 1$. This is for instance the definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuntz_algebra) and also in the original [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103901288), which also states that orthogonoality $s_i^*s_j=\delta_{ij}$ follows from this definition.

How does this follow from the definition?

It is easy to see from the concrete C*-algebra construction of $\mathcal O_n$ that orthogonality is satisfied. So once you know this algebra is universal and also simple, it follows that for any such operators one has orthogonality $s_i^*s_j = \delta_{ij}$. Is this what is meant when it is said that it follows from the equation, or is it more obvious? At least in the case of $n=2$ it can easily be proven algebraically.

(Note: This question came up when thinking about [find a unitary element in Cuntz algebra $\mathcal{O}_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354195/find-a-unitary-element-in-cuntz-algebra-mathcalo-n/3354230?noredirect=1#comment6904561_3354230))

Comment: This turned out to be basically a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117702/orthogonal-projections-with-sum-p-i-i-proving-that-i-ne-j-rightarrow-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that if we have two projections $p,q$, then $p + q$ is a projection if and only if $p$ and $q$ are orthogonal. Thus if you have partial isometries (or just isometries in this case) $v,w$ such that $vv^* + ww^*$ is a projection, then they necessarily have orthogonal ranges ($vv^*ww^* = 0$). Now since $v,w$ are partial isometries, $v = vv^*v, w = ww^*w$, and so

$$ v^*w = v^*vv^*ww^*w = v^*(vv^*)(ww^*)w = 0. $$

In particular if $(s_j)_{j=1}^n$ are $n$ isometries satisfying the Cuntz relation, then they have orthogonal ranges and $s_i^*s_j = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98653/discussion-on-answer-by-pstheman-definition-of-cuntz-algebra-clarification-about).